# In-app purchase restoring issue with sandbox environment

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, restore, storekit

I am working with in-app purchase in iOS, I have non-consumable type with my purchases. I already purchased the things and now testing for restoration process.
When I going to restore its ask me apple user id and password and after that its showing me popup with text

> "You've already purchased this but it hasn't bee downloaded. [Environment: Sandbox]"

If I click OK then nothing is happening.

I am stuck with this and can't find the way. Can somebody help me for this please??

Here is the delegate method which I have used.

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{

for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions){

    switch(transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
        {
            NSLog(@"purchasing");
            break;
        }//new
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
        {
            NSLog(@"purchased");
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];

           // unlocking data code

            break;
        }//new
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
        {
            NSLog(@"In the restoring state");
            break;

        }//new
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
        {
            ////////v//////nnn////////NSLog(@"failed");
            switch (transaction.error.code)
            {
                case SKErrorUnknown:
                    NSLog(@"SKErrorUnknown");
                    break;
                case SKErrorClientInvalid:
                    NSLog(@"SKErrorClientInvalid");
                    break;
                case SKErrorPaymentCancelled:
                    NSLog(@"cancelled");
                    break;
                case SKErrorPaymentInvalid:
                    NSLog(@"SKErrorPaymentInvalid");
                    break;
                case SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed:
                    NSLog(@"SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed");
                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"No Match Found for error");
                    break;
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]removeTransactionObserver:self];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When adding an IAP in iTunesConnect, you choose wether to host it with Apple or not (check the SS below), the alert posted seems to indicate that you choose to host contents with Apple although I assume you didn't host anything on Apple servers, if that is your case, make sure to choose the "NO" option as per below SS.

Hope it helps.

[image: IAP hosting]

Comment: Hello, Thank you for you reply. I have checked this option with iTunesConnect but its already off. Is there any another way to solve this?

Comment: what happens if you try to purchase (not restore) ?

Comment: Hi when I am going for purchase its showing me the popup saying "You've already purchased this but it hasn't bee downloaded. [Environment: Sandbox]". I am working with testing environment, Is that a problem? And now I am getting another one that say's "You've already purchased this would you like to restore it for free?."

Comment: The response "You've already purchased this would you like to restore it for free?." is what I would expect with an attempt to restore a non-consumable, since these cannot be purchased more than once. One question that is a little off topic-- when you get a failure, why do you do: [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]removeTransactionObserver:self]; ?

Comment: BTW, how did you know that SKErrorDomain was used with NSError in this case?

Comment: try adding another IAP, and try to purchase it, what would happen ?

Answer (score 0):

did you ever:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```